# How to get default property values in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using this version of Spark : `spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6` . I want to check few default properties. So I gave the following statement in `spark-shell`

```
scala> sqlContext.getConf("spark.sql.hive.metastore.version")
```

I was expecting the call to method `getConf` to return a value of `0.13.1` as desribed in this [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interacting-with-different-versions-of-hive-metastore). But I got the below exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.sql.hive.metastore.version
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf$$anonfun$getConf$1.apply(SQLConf.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf$$anonfun$getConf$1.apply(SQLConf.scala:283)
```

Am I retrieving the properties in the right way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
sc.getConf.toDebugString
```

OR

```
sqlContext.getAllConfs
```

which will return all values that have been set, however some defaults are in the code. In your specific example, [it is indeed in the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e14b545d2dcbc4587688b4c46718d3680b0a2f67/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.scala#L112):

```
getConf(HIVE_METASTORE_VERSION, hiveExecutionVersion)
```

where the default [is indeed in the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e14b545d2dcbc4587688b4c46718d3680b0a2f67/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.scala#L518):

```
val hiveExecutionVersion: String = "0.13.1"
```

So, `getConf` will attempt to pull the metastore version from the config, falling back to a default, but this is not listed in the conf itself.

Answer (score 5):

In Spark 2.x.x If I wanted to know default value of a Spark Conf I would do this:

Below command will return a Scala Map in spark-shell.

```
spark.sqlContext.getAllConfs
```

To find our value for a conf property:

e.g. - To find the default warehouse dir used by spark set to conf -
spark.sql.warehouse.dir:

```
spark.sqlContext.getAllConfs.get("spark.sql.warehouse.dir")
```