# Getting default spark config values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Spark versions 2.4 (sometimes 3.1), PySpark 2.4, Python 3.7 on RHEL. Explicit PySpark spark config can be retrieved with:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName('my_spark_app')
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "2")
    .getOrCreate()
)
spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
# or
spark.sparkContext.getConf().toDebugString()
```

But these do not include the default values. E.g. from [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/configuration.html#application-properties) there should be spark.executor.memory "1g". Instead, we see (missing) `None` values:

```
>>> dict(spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()).get('spark.executor.memory', 'None')
None
```

This is inconvenient for debugging runtime spark configuration settings in a variety of admin-managed environments.

Perhaps this was possible before in [earlier versions or in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467998/how-to-get-default-property-values-in-spark), but [not more recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807863/how-to-get-all-the-spark-config-along-with-default-config)?

I would expect the above code to return "1g". Any idea how?

Comment: I tested a Spark program with version 3.10. And if the config properties are default, they will not be displayed. However, if a config property assigns its default value in the program, it will appear. Therefore, I think if any config property is not displayed with those two methods, just understand that it contains default value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your SPARK UI enabled you can the [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#environment-variables) use it to provide your environment information:

- Spark 3:

  `appId = spark.sparkContext.applicationId`
- Spark 2:

  `appId = spark_session._sc.applicationId`

```
# spark is an existing SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
from urllib.request import urlopen

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

url = "http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/"+appId+"/environment"
jsonData = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([jsonData])
df = spark.read.json(rdd)
# Displays the content of the DataFrame to stdout
df.show()
```

If you have already turned on the spark history server, it will have records of previous runs so that you can look at previous runs and their environments.(Look at the environment tab for the job)  This might be easier to look at and was built specifically for what you are trying to do.

Another way that check the environment for settings.
[Is it possible to get the current spark context settings in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560241/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-spark-context-settings-in-pyspark)

Comment: Note from docs: "Note that only values explicitly specified through spark-defaults.conf, SparkConf, or the command line will appear. For all other configuration properties, you can assume the default value is used."